# Rails getting module with constantize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class under the namespace of a module, say

```
Module::Klass
```

I am able to access `Klass` from the console and it gives me :

```
Module::Klass
```

However, if I try to use:

```
"klass".constantize # Calling constantize on String
```

It errors out as it doesn't append the module namespace.

So, My question is : Is there a way to constantize the string according to its current context, so that I receive the klass name along with its module ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with constantize:

> The name is assumed to be the one of a top-level constant, no matter
>   whether it starts with “::” or not. No lexical context is taken into
>   account:
>
> ```
> C = 'outside'
> module M
>   C = 'inside'
>   C               # => 'inside'
>   "C".constantize # => 'outside', same as ::C
> end
> ```

But you can use const_get():

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def self.greet
      puts 'hi'
    end
  end

  const_get("MyClass").greet  
end

--output:--
hi
```

Comment: You can use `'Foo::Bar'.constantize`, though. Your answer is a little ambiguous on this (or maybe it's just me).

Comment: I answered the question that was asked, and I thought that posting the quote from the constantize docs made it clear that all constants are looked up starting at the top level.  However, I guess if you don't know how constants work in ruby, it is meaningless.

Answer (score 16):

If by "current context" you mean that you are currently within that module, you can access its constants directly.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end

  self.const_get('Bar') # => Foo::Bar
end
```

You can, of course, do it if you're outside of `Foo`.

```
Foo.const_get('Bar') # => Foo::Bar
```